# How to stretch the bottom pixels of image to full screen that the content mode is scaleAspectFill on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to set an image as background that the content mode is `scaleAspectFill` and stretch the bottom pixel of line to fullscreen.

Here is a simple sample image that the size is 1280x300px that will be set in Assets as 2x.
[image: sample image 1]

Here is a screenshot of the storyboard. I want to fill the the bottom pixel of line to the white space.

[image: sample image 2]

I have tried the `Stretching` and the `Slicing` feature but both effect are  not what I want.

[image: sample image 3] 
[image]

[image: sample image 5]

Here is the expected result what I want on iPhone 4S.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear how you are sizing your image...

The `1280 x 300` image you posted, with the imageView constrained to the width of the view...

AspectFit:

[image]

AspectFill (using the image's original 300 height):

[image]

AspectFill (using 150 height):

[image]

However, assuming the text in your images will have varying lengths, you may wind up with...

AspectFit:

[image]

AspectFill (using 150 height):

[image]

However... assuming you have a plan for solving that, one approach would be to use two image views.

[image]

The top image view would hold your full image as you already have it... using `.scaleAspectFill` and constraining its height to show just the centered text in the image.

The bottom image view would be constrained to the bottom of the view, with `.scaleToFill`, and you could use this extension:

```
extension UIImage {

    // return the CGRect portion as a new UIImage
    func subImage(in rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        guard let crop = cgImage.cropping(to: rect) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: crop, scale: scale, orientation:.up)
    }

}

// then, use it like this
let bottomImage = fullImage.subImage(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: fullImage.size.height - 1.0, width: 8.0, height: 1.0))
```

to get an `8px x 1px` portion of the original image. Set the `.image` of the bottom image view to that image and it will scale to fill the entire frame.

Result:

[image]

and here is a complete example, using your original image (I named it "wake.png"):

```
extension UIImage {

    // return the CGRect portion as a new UIImage
    func subImage(in rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return nil }
        guard let crop = cgImage.cropping(to: rect) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: crop, scale: scale, orientation:.up)
    }

}

class StretchBottomViewController: UIViewController {

    var topImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()

    var bottomImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(topImageView)
        view.addSubview(bottomImageView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain top image view to top / leading / trailing at Zero
            topImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            topImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain bottom image view to bottom of top image view / leading / trailing at Zero
            bottomImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bottomImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constrain bottom image view to bottom at Zero
            bottomImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // however you are determining the height of the top image view
            // using 150 here to work with your original image
            topImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),

        ])

        // load "wake me up" image
        if let fullImage = UIImage(named: "wake") {
            // get the bottom part of the full image (8 pixels wide, 1-pixel tall)
            if let bottomImage = fullImage.subImage(in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: fullImage.size.height - 1.0, width: 8.0, height: 1.0)) {
                topImageView.image = fullImage
                bottomImageView.image = bottomImage
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `(UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets resizingMode:(UIImageResizingMode)resizingMode` with `resizingModel` is `.stretch`

If you want the text is docked at the top, the blue vertical line is in the bottom, so let's try this (assuming that the blue line height is 20px, the distance from the top of image to bottom of text 'Before you go' is 100 px)

```
let image = yourOriginalImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10), resizingMode: .stretch)
```

Hope it helps.

**Update**

Below is what display with the above lines of code

[image: replace 3E8Wl to 3E8Wlm]

Comment: I had tried that is not work. The effect of `resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:` is same as the `Slicing` feature.

Comment: Could you show me the expected result (the image that you want)?

Comment: Ok, and pls give me your image (your png file)

Comment: you can download the first image on my post.

Comment: I tried your image with my above lines of code and the expectation is what you want.   I updated my answer with attached image, pls take a look.

Comment: have you set the content mode to `scaleAspectFill `?

Comment: hmm, it's quite conflicted because if you set contentMode is aspectFill, that mean the ratio of the image is constantly so i havent found out the solution for your expectation yet.